# Change date to day + 1 in a pandas dataframe where time = 00:00:00

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

[image]

If you see in the image of my dataframe, I have time points where midnight is a day behind what it should be, which affects my time series graphs.

I tried df.replace() where I passed in lists a and b:

```
df.replace(to_replace=a,value=b,inplace=True)
```

This just replaced all values in a with just the same one value in b instead of all the values in the list.

I also tried passing in a dictionary but received:
Value Error: "Replacement not allowed with overlapping keys and values"

Is there any way I can change either the dates in either the date column or the date_time column to day+1 for instances where time is 00:00:00 ?
Maybe using pandas map() method with strftime format?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something in this context

```
df.loc[df['time'] == datetime.time(0, 0), 'date'] += datetime.timedelta(days+1)
```

It selects the rows where the time is `00:00`. Only on that rows, you increase the date-column by one day.